# Regarding my python code

Tags: python

This is my code, while I am running my function rwpos() is supposed to return something, but it is not returning anything. Please help me through this...

```
import random

def rs():
    return random.choice([-1,1])

def rwpos(start,nsteps):
        if nsteps == 0:
                print start,nsteps
                return start
        else:
                start = start + rs()
                rwpos(start,nsteps-1)

x = rwpos(40,4)
print x
```

x is printing None ...
~

Comment: `return rwpos(start,nsteps-1)`

Comment: you miss a `return` statement in the `else` branch

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def rs():
    return random.choice([-1,1])

def rwpos(start,nsteps):

    if nsteps == 0:
        print start,nsteps
    else:
        start = start + rs()
        return rwpos(start,nsteps-1)

x = rwpos(40,4)
print x
```

You were not returning in the else statement.